# Java LocalTime overlaps with set of LocalTimes

Tags: java, overlap, localtime

I am looking for an algorithm which checks if a LocalTime pair overlaps with an ArrayList of LocalTime pairs.

I've tried manually adding several if's, but I'm not covering all cases.

```
public boolean formsOverlap() {

    for (ControlSchedule cs: table.getItems()) {

        if (startSpinner.getValue().isAfter(cs.getStartTime())
            && startSpinner.getValue().isBefore(cs.getEndTime()))
            return true;
        if (endSpinner.getValue().isAfter(cs.getStartTime())
            && endSpinner.getValue().isBefore(cs.getEndTime()))
            return true;
        if (cs.getStartTime().isAfter(startSpinner.getValue())
            && cs.getEndTime().isBefore(endSpinner.getValue()))
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your attempt or at least a minimal example of it?

Comment: How is `overlap` defined?

Comment: @deHaar I added my attempt.

Comment: @Thomas I think I explained myself wrong. It consists of LocalTime PAIRS. Let's say there is a pair from 9:00 to 10:00 and another one from 10:00 to 11:00. I shouldn't be allowed to insert a new pair from 8:00 to 12:00 for example.